# Report Builder PDF

Tags: oraclereports

I have Stored path in Oracle Database of Different Images and Pictures are stored in folder.THe Size of Pictures are in kb but when i run the Report from Oracle Report Builder and Generate it into PDF its size become more than 50MB.What will be the  problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inner format of pdf file could drusticly overweight incoming data))
Try to save txt file and then save same text in docx and fill the difference))

Comment: But I need PDF Strictly please give some solution

Comment: Try to create void PDF document vith your Oracle Report Builder. What size it has?